# Can't read .cso files but I can read their .hlsl versions?

Tags: c++, directx, hlsl

Well I've been trying to read a .cso file to use as a shader for a DirectX program I'm currently making.

Problem is no matter how I implemented a way to read the file it never worked. And after fidgeting around I discover that it's only the .cso files I can't read.

I can read anything else (which means it works) even their .hlsl files. Which is strange because the .hlsl (high level shader language) files are supposed to turn into .cso (compiled shader object) files.

What I'm currently doing is:

```
vector<byte> Read(string File){
    vector<byte> Text;
    fstream file(File, ios::in | ios::ate | ios::binary);

    if(file.is_open()){
        Text.resize(file.tellg());
        file.seekg(0 , ios::beg);
        file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&Text[0]), Text.size());
        file.close();
    }        

    return Text;
};
```

If I then implement it.

```
Read("VertexShader.hlsl"); //Works
Read("VertexShader.cso"); //Doesn't Works?!?!
```

And I need the .cso version of the shader to draw my sexy triangles. Without it my life and application will never continue and I have no idea what could be wrong.

EDIT #1:
When I read the .hlsl file the vector get's filled whit what was written in the file.
For the .cso ones the function doesn't even pass the "if(file.is_open)" test and stays empty.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you do not pass `ios::ate` to the `fstream` constructor, instead open the file, then `seekg` to the end to figure out the size?

Comment: @Praetorian None whatsoever. But I feel it's shorter and more compact that way.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What exactly happens when you read the .cso? The application crashes? No data is read? The data comes in corrupted?

Comment: Make sure the file exists!

Comment: @zdd Actually I'm not sure if it does exists or not. I believe it does since .hlsl turn into .cso files when compiling. Now if there was a setting I was supposed to change in Visual Studio then I'm sure I didn't do it.

Comment: @JaderJRivera well, then you should probably check if it is there. Because code that works for file a must work for file b too, if it is about general binary input. Basically you should use [`open()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/open/) and check for the [failbit](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/iostate/)

Comment: By default CSO objects are dumped into the output directory of your project. Visual studio default debug directory is the project directory. You will need to make sure the CSO objects are in the project directory, or update your debug working directory, or correctly specify a relative path when loading your file.

Comment: Two weeks later I finally realized the file path was the problem. It seems the .cso file were created in the same folder as the end application and not in the folder were all my sources and headers were. I guess the relative path thing should work since the full path does. I'll try it now and thanks a lot. (I feel dumb T-T)

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the problem.

Seems that the .hlsl turns into .cso files automatically for Windows 8 Applications but not for Windows 7 Applications (and others I guess). So my previous attempt to read the .cso file directly wouldn't work since the file never existed to begin with. Though I thought it would since I started to learn DirectX for Windows 8 first.

For windows 7 you have to compile the shader yourself and use that information.

Here's what I did:

```
#include <d3dcompiler.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "d3dcompiler.lib")

ID3D10Blob *blob, *blob2; //these hold the compiled shader data

D3DCompileFromFile(
    L"VertexShader.hlsl", NULL, NULL, "main", "vs_5_0", 0, 0, &blob, 0);

D3DCompileFromFile(
    L"PixelShader.hlsl", NULL, NULL, "main", "ps_5_0", 0, 0, &blob2, 0);


//Now you can just use the data with blob->GetBufferPointer(); 
//Or it's size with blob->GetBufferSize();


md3device->CreateVertexShader(
    blob->GetBufferPointer(), blob->GetBufferSize(), nullptr, &mVertexShader);

md3devicecontext->VSSetShader(mVertexShader, nullptr, 0);
```

Hope other people find this useful and helpful.I couldn't find info on this anywhere but found the function syntax on msdn and decided to try it since I had no other lead and it worked. (Hence I came up with the fact that Windows 7 doesn't compile it for you)

Comment: There is no magic in Windows 8 compared to Windows 7, you probably  forgot to compile your shaders. Using `D3DCompile*` stuff is not recommended nowadays and compilation to `.cso` is supposed to be done offline with `fxc.exe`. That's exactly what Visual Studio (since version 2012) do automatically when you press "build" with `.hlsl` files **added to project**.